# How to read Array of data from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to Iterate Array of data in json Please Check my code

```
Object {bhanu : Array[3], root: Array[12], hari: Array[7], balu: Array[1], santha: Array[6]}
```

I want to Iterate this array How can do this
  I am using like this

```
function orgChartResult(result)
{
    var userOrgUsers = JSON.parse(result);

    for(var name in userOrgUsers) {
        console.log(name + "=" + userOrgUsers[name]);
    }

    console.log(userOrgUsers);
}
```

but it's give all data  .But I want to read firstNode data only Means in bhanu:Arrat[3]; My array size is 3 then next array size is 12 how can i read one by one

Comment: You're asking how to read each item in an Array? Is that your question? ...And I have no idea what *"firstNode data only Means in bhanu:Arrat[3];"* means.

Comment: If I've understood correctly you want to try `for(var i in userOrgUsers.bhanu) { console.log(userOrgUsers.bhanu[i]; }`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP You shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over an array.

Comment: @crush It's a test to see if that's the data he wants... it's fine

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: It's not fine. Don't suggest bad practices to beginners.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP What happens when he decides he wants to do more than test the value there? Leaves the `for...in` loop, then later copy/pastes some grande javascript solution from the interwebs that modifies the Array prototype, and then he can't figure out why his website is broken.

Comment: @crush If the OP doesn't know that for loops include extended properties, they shouldn't be dealing with JSON objects or, I would assume, AJAX. That syntax is fine when you know what you're doing.. It's not evil. Just running that test code will probably show up the flaws of untampered `for` loops anyway - give the guy some credit

Comment: HI Thanks for the replay but i got dynamic values here insted of bhanu i got any value

Comment: i am using userOrgUsers.length but it's give undefined  exception .

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: It has nothing to do with JSON or AJAX. And no, beginners don't know that `for-in` includes inherited properties. Nor do they know that it doesn't guarantee the order of enumeration. This is why JavaScript developers who are knowledgeable don't use it on Arrays. Please don't suggest it.

Comment: @user2767541: You already know how to get to the array. `userOrgUsers[name]` So you'd add `.length` to that. SmokeyPHP's comment above used `.bhanu`, which didn't make sense for your situation.

Comment: yes ..but it's give how may objects is there those objects with commasepared for example in bhanu:Array[3] when i use userOrgUsrs[bhanu] it's give  like this bhanu=[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] but i want to read firstObject based on this object i want to do some operation then second object....

Comment: But it seems like he didn't know all the elements in the JSON object. How do you iterate through them, then, I wonder?

Comment: but when i read userOrgUsers[name][0] it's give firstobject data like that can use any for loop because i got this objects dynamically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll just go ahead and answer this since it seems you just need to loop the Array.

```
function orgChartResult(result) {
    var userOrgUsers = JSON.parse(result);

    for(var name in userOrgUsers) {
        console.log(name + "=" + userOrgUsers[name]);

        for (var i = 0; i < userOrgUsers[name].length; i++) {
            console.log(userOrgUsers[name][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So this just does a very typical `for` loop over the Arrays found at `userOrgUsers[name]`.

---

If each item in the Arrays are also objects, you can add yet another loop to enumerate the properties.

```
function orgChartResult(result) {
    var userOrgUsers = JSON.parse(result);

    for(var name in userOrgUsers) {
        console.log(name + "=" + userOrgUsers[name]);

        for (var i = 0; i < userOrgUsers[name].length; i++) {
            console.log(userOrgUsers[name][i]);

            for (var name2 in userOrgUsers[name][i]) {
                console.log(userOrgUsers[name][i][name2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you don't know the structure of the JSON for some reason, you can use a recursive function that will iterate any Array and Object, and invoke a callback on all other members. There are many other questions out there that deal with this scenario.